# Error:Could not find or load main

Tags: java, eclipse

It gives me that error when I launch, the class name is AQueueClass
Any help?

```
 package `com.thekyle.hi;`

    class QDemo {
        // a queue class for characters
        char q[]; // this array holds the queue
        int putloc, getloc; // the put and get indices

        QDemo(int size) {
            q = new char[size + 1];
            putloc = getloc = 0;

        }// put a character into the queue

        void put(char ch) {
            if (putloc == q.length - 1) {
                System.out.println(" - Queue is full silly- ");
                return;
            }

            putloc++;
            q[putloc] = ch;

        }

        char get() {// gets a character from the queue
            if (getloc == putloc) {
                System.out.println(" Queue is empty");
                return (char) 0;
            }
            getloc++;
            return q[getloc];
        }
    }
           class AQueueClass {
            public static void main(String args[]) {        
                QDemo bigQ = new QDemo(100);
                QDemo smallQ = new QDemo(4);
                char ch;
                int i;
                System.out.println("Using bigQ to store the alphabet");
                for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                    bigQ.put((char) ('A' + i));
                    // retrieve and display elements from bigQ
                    System.out.println("Contents of bigQ: ");
                    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                        ch = bigQ.get();
                        if (ch != (char) 0)
                            System.out.print(ch);

                    }
                    System.out.println("\n");
                    System.out.println("Using small q to generate errors");
                    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        System.out.print("Attemting to store " + (char) ('Z' - i));
                        smallQ.put((char)('Z' - i));
                        System.out.println();

                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Contents of smallQ: ");
                    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        ch = smallQ.get();
                        if( ch != (char) 0 ) System.out.print(ch);
                    }


                }

            }
        }
```

If its a class path problem, where do I find the class path? And since it says that I need more detail, so here is some filler.

Comment: "And since it says that I need more detail". You'd better added some instead of a useless filler. Something like the complete error message or how you try to start your class... and are those ticks really around your package declaration?

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class com.thekyle.hi.AQueueClass$BigE

Answer (score 0):

By what name you have save your java file. If you have two class in your java file then try to made you class containing **main()** method as a public class.

Comment: I followed the code in the book to the word, so it might be  a class path problem. But I do not know where that is.

Comment: Thanks, you solved it, but a new error arose, and I have to wait 3 days to ask it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save your file by the name **AQueueClass** and also add **public** keyword in front of **AQueueClass** class. Compile it and again run it. I think it will work .